# Profiling CherryPy

Tags: python, profiling, cherrypy, middleware

I've been trying to start profiling my CherryPy webserver, but the documentation is lacking in detail in how this should be set up. I understand that I should be able to use `cherrypy.lib.profiler` as middleware to mount my initial server. Right now, I have code like the following:

```
server_app = ServerClass()
cherrypy.tree.mount(server_app, '/', '/path/to/config/file.cfg')
cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

I want to mount the profiling middleware, and it seems that something like the following is required:

```
from cherrypy.lib import profiler

server_app = ServerClass()
server_cpapp = cherrypy.Application(server_app, '/', '/path/to/config/file.cfg')
server_profile_cpapp = profiler.make_app(server_cpapp, '/home/ken/tmp/cprofile', True)
#cherrypy.tree.mount(server_profile_cpapp)
cherrypy.tree.graft(server_profile_cpapp)

cherrypy.engine.start()
cherrypy.engine.block()
```

For some reason `cherrypy.tree.mount` doesn't work, but if I use `cherrypy.tree.graft` all seems to operate fine (I can make requests to the server as normal)

However, the above code generates a `cp_0001.prof` file under `/home/ken/tmp/cprofile` and I am not sure how to interpret it. I have tried using `pyprof2calltree` to read the data into KCacheGrind, but I get a parsing error. Does what I'm doing seem correct, and if so how do I interpret the output file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the profile files generated by CherryPy can be interpreted using the `profiler.py` script shipped as part of CherryPy. Simply run `profiler.py` in the `<site-packages>/cherrypy/lib` directory as follows:

```
python profiler.py /directory/containing/prof/files 8080
```

Then navigate to `localhost:8080` in your browser and the profiling results for all `.prof` files in the target directory will be displayed in a simple text interface.

I would still prefer to be able to export the results into a calltree to profile using KCacheGrind, but this seems to do for basic profiling.

This is documented in the [change log for v2.1 of CherryPy](https://bitbucket.org/cherrypy/cherrypy/wiki/WhatsNewIn21) when the profiler was introduced (although the other details on that page describing how to set up the profiler has since become deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

I am also trying to get profiling up and running for a cherrypy instance. I used the same code you have in your initial question, which seems to work in that it generates a cp_0001.prof file in the folder.

To answer your question, I am able to open this file in runsnakerun to see the profiling output in a tree view.

The problem I have is that every request I do to the server now fails, with the following output in the log:

```
[29/May/2013:16:39:32] ENGINE AssertionError('Bad call', ('', 0, 'sleep'), <frame object at 0x08522400>, <frame object at 0x08522030>, <frame object at 0x08156748>, <frame object at 0x06D06F10>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\_cptree.py", line 290, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\lib\profiler.py", line 188, in __call__
    return self.profiler.run(gather)
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\lib\profiler.py", line 147, in run
    result = self.profiler.runcall(func, *args)
  File "<path>\python\lib\profile.py", line 472, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "<path>\packages\cherrypy\lib\profiler.py", line 183, in gather
    def gather():
  File "<path>\python\lib\profile.py", line 246, in trace_dispatch_i
    if self.dispatch[event](self, frame, t):
  File "<path>\python\lib\profile.py", line 301, in trace_dispatch_call
     frame, frame.f_back)
AssertionError: ('Bad call', ('', 0, 'sleep'), <frame object at 0x08522400>, <frame object at 0x08522030>, <frame object at 0x08156748>, <frame object at 0x06D06F10>)
```

I am using python 2.6.6 and cherrypy 3.2.2

Any suggestions?

Comment: Getting this as well.