# Profiling CherryPy: convert results to graphic format

Tags: python, profiling, cherrypy

I try to profile my CherryPy web server and as a result I have some `.prof`  files. I can read them in text format by using web browser what was described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16630208/profiling-cherrypy?rq=1). But I need to export the results into a calltree to profile using, for example, KCacheGrind or Gprof2Dot.

But Gprof2Dot give me an error:

> profile_results>gprof2dot.py -f prof out.prof | dot -Tpng -o out.png
>
> error: unexpected end of file

And KCacheGrind doesn't know about `.prof` files...

Are there any ways to take a calltree in graphic format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use pstats.

```
gprof2dot -f pstats out.prof | dot -Tpng -o out.png
```

CherryPy uses python cProfile/profile.

[Here is the reference on the docs](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot#python_profile)

Comment: A note: gprof2dot fails with «error: failed to load …» for any versions newer than tag 2016.10.13 (as of 2017-10-31).